# Why always come default value from RangeSet to the constraint in Pyomo?

Tags: python, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization

I couldn't have i+1 value for the last value of the RangeSet, therefore I want to ignore it in the constraint. However, I couldn't do that because i value always comes as default value. So, it does not enter to if statement. How can I solve the problem ?

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

model = pyo.AbstractModel()

number_of_lane=2
number_of_vehicle=2

model.i = pyo.Param(within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers, default=number_of_lane)
model.j = pyo.Param(within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers, default=number_of_vehicle)

model.I = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.i)
model.J = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.j)

model.R = pyo.Param(default=0.5) #CAV's reaction (s)
model.D = pyo.Param(default=1.5) #Safety Distance (m)
model.lv = pyo.Param(default=4) #Length of vehicle (m)

model.xr = pyo.Param(model.I, model.J, within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers, initialize=xr_cons)
model.x = pyo.Var(model.I, model.J, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals, initialize=(0))

def lane_crossing_constraint_rule(m, i, j): #lane should be 2, vehicles will be the first one which is close to the intersection
    m.i.pprint() #There is a problem about taking i and j value
    if(m.i.value<number_of_vehicle): #Always comes equal!!!!
        return (m.x[i,j]-m.xr[i,j])**2+(m.x[i+1,j]-m.xr[i+1,j])**2>=(m.lv+m.D)
    else:
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip

# the next line creates one constraint for each member of the set model.I
model.l1Constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.I, model.J, rule=lane_crossing_constraint_rule)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't super clear what you are trying to do with the model setup you've chosen.  Why did you select `AbstractModel()`?  Your example isn't reproducible because it is missing data and you aren't building a model instance.  Further, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish by initializing your range set size from the value of a parameter?

I think you should start with a `ConcreteModel()`, get something working, and build out from there, if needed.  Build a little bit at a time, **print** the model and verify it, then add to it.

Here is a small example that I think shows some of the things you are trying to do.  It is a `ConcreteModel` that builds a range set, a variable, and shows how to make a constraint that is dependent on the value of the index from the set `Lanes`

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

number_of_lanes = 5

model.Lanes = pyo.RangeSet(1, number_of_lanes)

model.car_speed = pyo.Var(model.Lanes, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)


def lane_speed(model, lane):
    if lane < 4:
        return model.car_speed[lane] <= 60
    return pyo.Constraint.Skip


model.lane_speed = pyo.Constraint(model.Lanes, rule=lane_speed)

model.pprint()
```

##### Output

```
1 RangeSet Declarations
    Lanes : Dimen=1, Size=5, Bounds=(1, 5)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :   True :   [1:5]

1 Var Declarations
    car_speed : Size=5, Index=Lanes
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          2 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          3 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          4 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          5 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Constraint Declarations
    lane_speed : Size=3, Index=Lanes, Active=True
        Key : Lower : Body         : Upper : Active
          1 :  -Inf : car_speed[1] :  60.0 :   True
          2 :  -Inf : car_speed[2] :  60.0 :   True
          3 :  -Inf : car_speed[3] :  60.0 :   True

3 Declarations: Lanes car_speed lane_speed
```

Comment: The whole code is huge, I only want to solve that how can I pass set to the constraint and how can I use its value for i+1 index.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. Thanks to AirSquid for an example.

The solution:

```
def lane_crossing_constraint_rule(m, i, j): #lane should be 2, vehicles will be the first one which is close to the intersection
    if(i <number_of_vehicle):
        return (m.x[i,j]-m.xr[i,j])**2+(m.x[i+1,j]-m.xr[i+1,j])**2>=(m.lv+m.D)
    else:
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
```